# Is there a search bar that shows results in a sub screen in iOS/Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, searchbar

I have a screen with a UITableView. I would like to add to it a search bar (that searches on the internet) and shows the found results in a sub screen. When an item on the sub screen is clicked, I'd like to add it to my table. Is there such a search bar in iOS? I added a paint in order to make things clearer.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the UISearchController. With this, you can give it a view controller, and you can modify the view controller to have it where you want it.

Comment: There's no prebuilt option for this exactly. You'll have to create your own subclass to implement that functionality. Check out [this guide](http://shrikar.com/swift-ios-tutorial-uisearchbar-and-uisearchbardelegate/) it's not exactly what you're looking for but the general design will be the same.

Comment: Oh..that's a shame. Thank you, I'll examine this guide.

Answer (score 0):

`UITableViewController`s have a restriction: its main view must be a `UITableView` that takes up the entire screen space (except for a possible navigation bar at the top, and a toolbar or tab bar at the bottom).

If you want to have other views such as a `UISearchBar` you must use a `UIViewController` and add a `UITableView` and a `UISearchBar`

Comment: I don't use a UITableViewController. I was actually looking for an easy way to have the search bar I wanted since I'm new in iOS development.